# sed for back slash and tab char has error "unterminated `s' command"

Tags: sed

I have a line in the middle has a "\\t",  a back slash following a tab.  I need to replace  it with '\t' just a tab

```
sed -i -r 's/\\\t/\t/g' a.txt
```

it gives an error:

sed: -e expression #1, char 14: unterminated `s' command

cannot find any wrong.
Appreciate help

Comment: Sorry I make mistake  my code was ```sed -i -r 's/\\\t\/\t/g' a.txt.  an extra back slash

Comment: Don't say it in the comment, edit the question.

Comment: So is the sed command you posted in your question working for you?